# Android: Images of GroupIndicator in ExpandableListview not show fine

Tags: android, image, expandablelistview

I have created an app with a custom `ExpandableListView`. I have wanted to put an images in groupIndicator to left. But I get that the images show elongated to right. The size of the images is 100x100 px. How I can adjust the width of the images to the size of the expandable row?

**main.xml**

```
<ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/expandable"
                    style="@style/scrollbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/expandable"
                    android:listSelector="@color/negro"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:scrollingCache="false" />
```

**expandable.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_icono_abajo" android:state_empty="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_icono_arriba" android:state_expanded="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_icono_abajo" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:indicatorLeft="<some left padded value>dp"
android:indicatorRight="<left value + 100>dp"
```

to your `ExpandableListView`